# Auto update local webpage when image file is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, twitch, word-cloud

I'm working on a twitch.tv overlay that generates a word cloud live on-screen based on what I've been saying on stream.

I'm currently using Visual Studio Code with Live Server to display a file via an HTML file alongside a Python script that generates a new png file of the word cloud, using the same filename.

Using the Live Server extension is nice, but I can't help but feel like it's sort of a dirty solution. Any ideas on something more formal?

Comment: This seems to be a non-formal use case for me, in this case, one picks the solution that fits the needs

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs and Express could be a good option. The server could be written in Javascript and you could use a sub-process to call your python script on an interval.